# DataContractSerializer deserialization fails completely if just one value is missing

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

Is there any way to prevent `DataContractSerializer`'s Deserialize to ignore missing values and keep deserializing the rest of the data, instead of abandoning everything, throwing an Exception and returning `NULL`?

I'm actively building the applicaton, so naturally its objects get new fields added quite frequently, and the further along it gets, the more pain it is to have to re-enter all the data every time any object type gets an extra field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IsRequired` Property of the `DataMember` Attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute_properties.aspx

Example:

```
[DataContract]
public class Data
{
     [DataMember]
     public string Required { get; set; }

     [DataMember(IsRequired=false)]
     public string? NotRequired { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If the `[DataMember]` Attribute is specified the IsRequired property is *not required* unless IsRequired is explicitly set to true. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792(v=vs.110).aspx - "..the DataMemberAttribute attribute has an IsRequired property (*the default is false*)." In the example above, *both* the Required and NotRequired properties are *not required* by DataContractSerializer.